# Show line numbers only on command mode

Tags: vim

I only ever use the line numbers when I want to switch to a line on the screen, which I use the command mode for (e.g. :82)

Is there a way to show the line numbers when I switch to command mode?

Comment: It's "command-line mode".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use `map` for that.

```
: nnoremap : :set nu<CR>:
```

This will set line numbers when you enter command line mode.

The following command will not show line numbers when you leave command-line mode.

```
  :nnoremap <CR> :set nonu<CR>
```

But this needs two enters to be pressed.

** As Andrew suggests, the following command des the same and avoids typing enter twice.**

```
:cnoremap <silent> <CR> <CR>:set nonu<CR>
```

Put these two lines in your `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I try these commands, it says "No such group or event: CmdEnter"

Comment: @pyceanx : sorry, Its CmdwinEnter, not CmdEnter. Same for CmdwinLeave. Try this and tell :)

Comment: does not seem to work :< I've done some searching, and from what I've read the events for entering/leaving command-line mode do not exist. I don't think command-line mode is the command window. I found this solution: http://superuser.com/questions/293055/in-vim-can-i-run-an-autocommand-on-entering-command-line-mode , however, I don't know how to replicate it to test for leaving command-line mode.

Comment: Yeah, if I add 'set nu' in the function, it does set the numbers when I press : . Now I just need to unset it when I enter the command.

Comment: It works! There's only one slight problem: I have to hit enter twice for the numbers to not show. It feels a little odd. thank you, however, for sticking this out. :>

Comment: I think the second command needs to be: `cnoremap <CR> <CR>:set nonu<CR>`.

That way, pressing enter in command-line mode will remove line numbers, and it won't be necessary to press enter a second time :). 

It might also be a good idea to make it a `cnoremap <silent>` to avoid seeing the `:set nonu`.

Comment: Andrew , but your mapping doesn't allow me to close vim. When I press :q, I am receiving trailing characters error.

Comment: I think it was a problem with the placement of `<silent>` :). I've edited your response to correct it. Try out what I've put in your answer, there should be no "trailing characters" error anymore.